# Report product sold. I need the 'ordered_qty' as a negative value

Tags: reports

I need for an CSV Export the value/number (column "Anz." in the screenshot) of 'ordered_qty' as a negative value/number. Everything I tried doesn't work.

[image]

What can I insert in these lines to get an - before the number?
Hope somebody can help me fast and easy.
Thanks for your time.

```
$this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
            'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Anz.'),
            'width'     =>'120px',
            'align'     =>'right',
            'index'     =>'ordered_qty',
             ));


<?php


class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid


{
    /**
     * Sub report size
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $_subReportSize = 0;

    /**
     * Initialize Grid settings
     *
     */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('gridProductsSold');
}

/**
 * Prepare collection object for grid
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    $this->getCollection()
        ->initReport('reports/product_sold_collection');
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Prepare Grid columns
 *
 * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid
 */
protected function _prepareColumns()
{

$this->addColumn('EAN', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('EAN'),
        'index'     =>'wv_ean'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Bezeichnung'),
        'index'     =>'""'
    ));


$this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Anz.'),
        'width'     =>'120px',
        'align'     =>'right',
        'index'     =>'ordered_qty',

    ));

$this->addColumn('unit', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Einheit'),
        'index'     =>'unit'
    ));

$this->addColumn('qty', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Best.'),
        'index'     =>'""',

    ));

$this->addColumn('date', array(
        'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Eingang'),
        'index'     =>'""'
    ));


    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSoldCsv', Mage::helper('reports')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportSoldExcel', Mage::helper('reports')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
}
```

Comment: You want it negative in exported csv only or in grid also?

Comment: If it's only in csv negative it's also ok.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a custom renderer for that column.

```
$this->addColumn('ordered_qty', array(
    'header'    =>Mage::helper('reports')->__('Anz.'),
    'width'     =>'120px',
    'align'     =>'right',
    'index'     =>'ordered_qty',
    'renderer' => '[Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Column_Renderer_Negative'

));
```

then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/Adminhtml/Column/Renderer/Negative.php` with this content

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Adminhtml_Column_Renderer_Negative extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Number
{
    protected function _getValue(Varien_Object $row) 
    {
        $realValue = parent::getValue($row);
        //don't add minus if the value is 0.
        if ($value) {
            $value = 0 - $value;
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Marius for your inspiration, my solution:

insert this line in my Grid.php:

```
'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Negative'
```

and use this code as in a local Negative.php:

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Negative
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract

{
protected $_defaultWidth = 100;

/**
 * Returns value of the row
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $row
 * @return mixed|string
 */
protected function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $data = parent::_getValue($row);
    if (!is_null($data)) {
        $value = $data * -1;
        $sign = (bool)(int)$this->getColumn()->getShowNumberSign() && ($value > 0) ? '+' : '';
        if ($sign) {
            $value = $sign . $value;
        }
        return $value ? $value : '0'; // fixed for showing zero in grid
    }
    return $this->getColumn()->getDefault();
}

/**
 * Renders CSS
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function renderCss()
{
    return parent::renderCss() . ' a-right';
}
}
```